# How do I modify the bot and have it send the message to ID User instead of mentions or adding both methods?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

How do I modify the bot and have it send the DM message to ID User instead of mentions or adding both methods?
Example
#s UserID (my message )

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 let args = message.content.split(' ').slice(1);

 if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 's')) {
  let mnt = message.mentions.users.first();
  if (!mnt) return message.reply('Please mention someone!');
  mnt
   .send(args.join(' ').replace(mnt, ''))
   .then(() => {
    message.channel.send('Successfully sent the message!');
   })
   .catch(() => {
    message.channel.send('The user have dms disabled');
   });
 }
});
```

Comment: I know that and I've been looking for it all night and you try some of it and it fails, it might be simple for you. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can get a user via user ID with [`UserManager.cache`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache) and [`Collection.prototype.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get), or with [`UserManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/UserManager?scrollTo=cache) if your not sure whether the user is cached or not.

```js
// get user from cache
const user = client.users.cache.get(args[1]);
user.send('Something');

// make sure the function is async
const user = await client.users.fetch(args[1]);
// if the client does not share a guild with the user, you will not be able to send them anything
user.send?.('Something'); // so you should use optional chaining
```